# Reading sub-sites with files rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I'm using the REST Files API, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations), to read the content of an Online Sharepoint (Office 365) site.

Is it possible to get the sub-sites the root site using this API?

I understand I can get a list of sub-sites using the traditional SharePoint API (`https://<my-domain>.sharepoint.com/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos`), but I'd rather use the files API because I'm using it for other purposes as well.

(Note that the two APIs are very different. One example: getting the child-elements of a folder in the files API is done using `GET {base-url}/Files/{folder-id}/children`, which it's done using `http://<site url>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/<folder name>')/folders` in the 'classic' API).

In addition, once I get the list of sub-sites  - using the above endpoint or any other means - is it possible to traverse / read these sub-sites using the files REST API?

Comment: This is the REST endpoint `https://<my-domain>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webinfos` What sort of content are you intent on reading from the subsites?

Comment: I'd like to read all the documents and their content.

Answer (score 0):

This is the REST endpoint `https://<my-domain>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webinfos`

You can read the content of subsites by using the `%site%/_api/web/` endpoint; e.g: `%site%/_api/web/lists`

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't use the REST Files API I was referring to.

Comment: Try using  https://<site url>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files('file name')/$value